# Flexbox with background image disappears with flex-direction: column or column-reverse

Tags: html, css, flexbox, background-image

Once I use flex-direction: column-reverse; on the card, the card background image disappears.

Below is a snippet of the card structure which I would like to reverse the image to the top on mobile devices. However, I have not added the media queries code because it does not work there either.

The CSS snippet below which has the most important aspects of the styling for this specific question.

```css
.card {
  background-color: hsl(244, 38%, 16%);
  border-radius: 10px;
  display: flex;
  /* flex-direction: column-reverse; */
}

.card-info {
  flex: 1;
}

.card-image {
  flex: 2;
  background-image: url('../images/image-header-desktop.jpg');
  position: relative;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
  background-blend-mode: overlay;
  background-color: hsl(277deg 64% 61% / 66%);
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <div class="card-info">
    <h1>Get <span>insights</span> that help your business grow.</h1>
    <p>Discover the benefits of data analytics and make better decisions regarding revenue, customer experience, and overall efficiency.</p>
    <div class="stats">
      <div>
        <div class="vals">10k+</div>
        <div class="title">COMPANIES</div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <div class="vals">314</div>
        <div class="title">TEMPLATES</div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <div class="vals">12M+</div>
        <div class="title">QUERIES</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card-image">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need a media query to achieve this. So you can change flex-direction accordingly.

Without changing your code much you can add this:

```
//If width of viewport is less than equal to 630px, this styling will apply to .card.

@media screen and (max-width : 630px){
  .card {
 flex-direction: column-reverse; 
 height: 600px;
}
}
```

[Demo](https://codepen.io/tusharshahi/pen/GRmpjEQ)

Answer (score 0):

Because it is column-reverse. you can solve this problem by using row-reverse.

```
.card {
background-color: hsl(244, 38%, 16%);
border-radius: 10px;
display: flex;
flex-direction: row-reverse;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Point to note. I had an additional div around the card which had a height of 100vh. Which prevented the card from expanding when the content got larger than 100vh so I used a min-height instead.

I also added a min-height to .card-image since it technically had no content